# How to use Kendo UI Grid with both popup and inline modes?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

I am using Kendo Grid with custom popup template.

I want to use the `popup` and `inline` modes together. When adding new records, the grid should use `popup` mode and open my custom template; when editing, it should use `inline` mode.

I have referred to [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/7nj0pxwz/1/embedded/result/) in [this blog article](https://onabai.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/kendoui-grid-popup-editing-and-inline-editing-mixed-together/), which shows how to use the `popup` and `inline` modes together, but I am not able to render the popup with my custom template.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks.

Here is [my DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zv2dbk7s/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<h3>How to use Kendo-ui Grid use popup with custom template while adding and Inline while editing records</h3>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <h3>Edit Person</h3>
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age: <input data-role="numerictextbox" name="age" /></label>
  </p>
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var ds = {
    data: createRandomData(20),
    pageSize: 4,
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id: { type: 'number' },
                FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                LastName: { type: 'string' },
                City: { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
};

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    toolbar: [ { text : "Add new record", name: "create", iconClass: "k-icon k-add"} ],
    // editable: "inline",
    editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
    },
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 100, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 100, title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City", width: 100 },
        { command: [ "edit" ]}
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your and created this new [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/3zh24rf2).

You can use Kendo grid's [`setOptions`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) method **to dynamically change the edit mode to popup along with your `custom template`** like below:

```
$(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {
    // change grid editable mode to popup and set the popup editing template
    grid.setOptions({
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
        }
    });

    grid.addRow();
    grid.options.editable = "inline";
});
```